# WPF DataGridComboBoxColum - trigger on selecting value

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a DataGrid with several fields, one of it is a DataGridComboBoxColumn. On that one I add items dynamically depending on one field by default "Add items". If I have added `Item 1` and is currently selected, I'd like that when the user clicks on the dropdown and selects `Item 1` again I can trigger my source and edit that item. However currently using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` does not trigger any changes.

Looks like `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` is what I need, but I am not sure how to implement the UpdateSource() method to do what I want.

My xaml snippet

```
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ItemColumn" Header="{x:Static res:RES.HEADER}"
                                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Static res:RES.TOOLTIP}"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Item, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridComboBoxElementStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridComboBoxEditingElementStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

And I got  `string` *Item* and a `List<string>` *Items* properties to bind the fields.

Is it possible to get an example of how to use Explicit to get a trigger every time the user clicks on the dropdown of the Item, even if already selected? or is there any other way not using Explicit? I am using MVVM as much as possible so that's also a factor to consider.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question then - there is an event in ComboBox "OnDropDownOpened" if you stick with MVVM you can use attached property to listen for that event and fire the command.

Comment: Thanks Melkov V, I've edited my question, hope it's clearer now. What I'd need is to fire an event if the user selects the same dropdown item that is currently selected, as in this case my `Item 1` setter recognises it and opens an edit dialog. At the moment with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` that trigger does not happen

Comment: Then, solution from first answer is seems what you need. With MVVM its the same as my commentary above - just use ICommand binding for attached property and rise the command when detect in "OnDropDownClosed" that SelectedItem is the same as SelectedItem in "OnDropDownOpened"

Comment: Thank you mm8 and Melkor, indeed that solution is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedValueBinding` source property is only set if you select a *new* value.

If you want to do something when the the currently selected value is selected again, you could handle this in the view by for example handling the `DropDownOpened` and `DropDownClosed` events:

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    cmb.DropDownOpened += Cmb_DropDownOpened;
    cmb.DropDownClosed += Cmb_DropDownClosed;
}

string _selectedValue;
private void Cmb_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _selectedValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem as string;
}

private void Cmb_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem as string;
    if (selectedValue == _selectedValue)
    {
        //same value was selected...
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ComboBox_Loaded" />
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```